# Device Events for 2022 Q2 are missing

Tags: openfda, download

I want to ask why the Maude-Device-Event Files for Q2 are currently not available in the downloads. See:

- https://open.fda.gov/data/downloads/

It states last updated on 2022-06-23.

Answer (score 0):

i have found a workaround for my question. The Fda-Maude Website has a section with downloads. Those files seem to be recent and up-to-date. Im not sure if it's a good idea to use those instead of OpenFDA, but it is important to have latest files, and if OpenFDA is always hanging behind, this is problematic.

- https://www.fda.gov/medical-devices/mandatory-reporting-requirements-manufacturers-importers-and-device-user-facilities/about-manufacturer-and-user-facility-device-experience-maude